# Disable mouse capturing by Button

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, toolstrip, mousecapture

I create custom `ContextMenuStrip` with `Button` in it:

```
ContextMenuStrip _contextMenu = new ContextMenuStrip();
_contextMenu.Items.Add(new ToolStripMenuItem("Item"));
_contextMenu.Items.Add(new ToolStripControlHost(new Button()));
```

When I open this context menu and move mouse over 'Item' it is highlighted. But after I clicked `Button` and then move mouse over 'Item' again it isn't highlighted anymore. Looks like `Button` captures mouse. How can I avoid this or release capturing after `Button` clicking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create your own button class inherited from `Button` and set `ControlStyles.Selectable` to `false`, this will prevent it from taking focus:

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
    public MyButton()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, false);
    }
}
```

And then just use it instead of `Button`:

```
_contextMenu.Items.Add(new ToolStripControlHost(new MyButton()));
```